# SailsJS error: skill is not defined by edit view

Tags: rest, crud, sails.js, ejs

I'm building an application where people can put there skills in. I made a edit controller with this code:

```
  /**
   * Action blueprints:
   *    `/skill/edit`
   */
  edit: function(req, res, next) {
    Skill.findOne(req.param('id'), function foundSkill(err, skill) {
      // if skill is not find output an error
      if (err) return next(err);

      // if the skill is find
      if(!skill) return next();

      // Show skill
      res.view({
        skill:skill
      });
    });

    // Get an array of all categorys in the Category collecction
    Category.find(function foundCategorys(err, categorys) {
      // if category is not find output an error
      if (err) return next(err);

      // pass the array down to the /view/index.ejs page
      res.view({
        categorys:categorys
      });
    });

  },
```

By every skill a user must select an category. So i thought this is the way to achieve this.

This is the code inside the edit.ejs view file:

```
<div class="wrapper" id="skill_page">

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <article>
            <form action="/skill/update/<%= skill.id %>" method="POST" class="form-signin" id="edit-skill-form">
                <h2 class="form-sigin-heading">Edit an skill</h2>
                <div class="input-form">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Skill title" name="title" value="<%= skill.title %>">
                </div>
                <div class="input-form">
                    <select name="skillCat">
                        <option>Choose category</option>
                        <% for(category in categories) { %>
                        <option value="<%= category.id %>"><%= category.title %></option>
                        <% } %>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="input-form">
                    <label for="ratingType">Rating on or of</label>
                    <select name="ratingType" id="ratingType">
                        <option>Choose rating type</option>
                        <option>No-rating</option>
                        <option value="true">Rating</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Save changes">
                <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= _csrf %>">
            </form>
        </article>
    </div>  
</div>
```

When i lift the application with `sails lift` in the console, and go to the Skill edit page of an specific skill there comes a error like this:

```
error: Error rendering view at :: /vagrant/Skillsmatrix/views/skill/edit
error: Using layout located at :: /vagrant/Skillsmatrix/views/layout
error: Server Error (500)
error: ReferenceError: /vagrant/Skillsmatrix/views/skill/edit.ejs:5
    3|  <div class="col-md-12">
    4|          <article>
 >> 5|                  <form action="/skill/update/<%=
skill.id %>" method="POST" class="form-signin" id="edit-skill-form">
    6|                          <h2 class="form-sigin-heading">Edit an skill</h2>
    7|                          <div class="input-form">
    8|                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Skill title" name="title" value="<%= skill.title %>">

skill is not defined
```

But i don't know how to solve the problem or what i did wrong. Specialy why the error `skill is not defined` comes in. If someone give's me help and/or feedback i'm really great-full!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

First, AFAIK, there's no callback in the action functions, so the signature should be more like `edit: function(req, res) {...`.

Second: you are running two queries (for skills and for categories) asynchronously, so the renderer never gets both values at the same time. If you need both skill and categories in your view, you are going to have to nest the calls. Something like:

```
/**
   * Action blueprints:
   *    `/skill/edit`
   */
  edit: function(req, res, next) {
    Skill.findOne(req.param('id'), function foundSkill(err, skill) {
      // if skill is not find output an error
      if (err) return res.serverError(err);

      // if the skill is find
      if(!skill) return res.notFound();

      // Get an array of all categories in the Category collection
      Category.find(function foundCategories(err, categories) {
        // if category is not find output an error
        if (err) return res.serverError(err);

        return res.view({
          skill: skill,
          categories: categories
        });
      });
    });    
  },
```

At the same time, it doesn't look like you are using categories in your view. So, if it's just some legacy code, just remove it (for it's causing your problem):

```
/**
   * Action blueprints:
   *    `/skill/edit`
   */
  edit: function(req, res, next) {
    Skill.findOne(req.param('id'), function foundSkill(err, skill) {
      // if skill is not find output an error
      if (err) return res.serverError(err);

      // if the skill is find
      if(!skill) return res.notFound();

      return res.view({
        skill: skill
      });
    });    
  },
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment @bredikhin! Someone near me helped me out! I'll post the answer below, so others can use it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Someone near me helped me out to figure out the solution. My problem was that i want to get 2 objects at the same time. And with the code i had it's not working.

So here is the solution how it's work:

```
  /**
   * Action blueprints:
   *    `/skill/edit`
   */
  edit: function(req, res, next) {

    Skill.findOne(req.param('id'), function foundSkill(result, skill) {
      Category.find(function foundCategorys(err, categories) {
        res.view({
          skill:skill,
          categories: categories
        });
      });
    });
  },
```

If someone has an better or more efficient way, i like to know!